# How i can find uniq records on base of some attribute in sort_by rails

Tags: ruby, arrays

Hi i have these records how i can find unique records in sort_by methods block

```
   my array is like this

     [#<Post id: 1, name: "ali", team_elo: 0, team_name: "solo", created_at: 
     "2012-12-09  16:11:17", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:39:43">,
     #<Post id: 2, name: "ramiz", team_elo: nil, team_name: "roko", created_at: 
     "2012-12-11 03:40:31", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:40:31">,
     #<Post id: 3, name: "ramizrt", team_elo: nil, team_name: "joko", created_at: 
      "2012-12-11 03:40:47", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:40:47">,
     #<Post id: 4, name: "lee", team_elo: nil, team_name: "roko", created_at: 
       "2012-12-11 03:41:15", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:41:15">]
```

how i can sort this array on base of unique team_name.The result should like this

```
       [#<Post id: 1, name: "ali", team_elo: 0, team_name: "solo", created_at: 
     "2012-12-09  16:11:17", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:39:43">,
     #<Post id: 2, name: "ramiz", team_elo: nil, team_name: "roko", created_at: 
     "2012-12-11 03:40:31", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:40:31">,
     #<Post id: 3, name: "ramizrt", team_elo: nil, team_name: "joko", created_at: 
      "2012-12-11 03:40:47", updated_at: "2012-12-11 03:40:47">]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
arr = arr.uniq { |x| x.team_name }
```

or its brother

```
arr.uniq! { |x| x.team_name }
```

which will set `arr` to only the elements you want.

Comment: it will also sort this as well

Comment: add the sort_by to the end: `arr = arr.uniq(&:team_name).sort_by(&:team_name)`
Keep in mind that this will run through the array twice, though.